# Keycloak - import SSL Certificate (start-dev)

Tags: java, linux, keycloak, keycloak-services

i try to play a bit around with a Keycloak installation on Linux. The Setup for the Keycloak Server from this Documantation worked fine. https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-zip

Now i try to enable TLS / HTTPS like descriped here -> https://www.keycloak.org/server/enabletls

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --https-certificate-file=/path/to/certfile.pem --https-certificate-key-file=/path/to/keyfile.pem
```

If i try to start it in Development Mode, i'll get the follwing Error:

```
2022-11-11 11:43:34,421 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2022-11-11 11:43:34,421 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start HTTP server
2022-11-11 11:43:34,421 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- or -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- or -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY----- delimiter
2022-11-11 11:43:34,421 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Missing -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- or -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- or -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY----- delimiter
```

I tried to Bind a Self- Signed and a Enterprise Certificate - both with the same result.
If i cat on the Files, everything looks fine.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Maybe its because of the Development Mode?
I would like to play around within the Dev. Mode (kc.sh start-dev)for a while befor i start going into Productive.

Thanks and Greetings

Comment: Is your certificate PEM formatted? Considering it's stating `Missing -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- delimiter`, it might be the issue.

Comment: yes the Sefl-Signed was created as .PEM. The Enterprise was .cer but i comverted it to PEM.